# How can I show a date from previous month in the same week

Tags: datepicker, react-dates

I'm trying to implement [SingleDatePicker](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates#singledatepicker) with days from the previous month falling in the first/last week of the month shown to be shown in a disabled state.

For example, if my current month in view starts on a Thursday, I want to show 3 days from previous month on the same month view, but disabled.

Is there any way I can do this?